# I want capture screen when any game is running with opengl

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is glReadPixels() failing in this code in iOS 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528365/why-is-glreadpixels-failing-in-this-code-in-ios-6-0)

I am developing a game with OpenGL, need a screen shot when best shot taken and upload facebook but when i take screen shot its only black screen. what i do ?
I also use code in link :
[take screen Programmatically of UIview+glview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197137/take-screen-programmatically-of-uiviewglview)
and similar code
but no success.

i am suing code from  : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html

But All code result an image in simulator not in device(in device only black or white)

Comment: The answer to the above-linked question (and my comment there) explains why your glReadPixels()-based code is returning a black image. You need to either capture the screen contents before they are presented or use retained backing.

Comment: i am using class which is subclass of OpenGLES2DView.In this class i want to take a screenshot, when use glReadPixels it's not worked in device but in simnulator go right.

Comment: Again, read the answer there. The reason your capture is failing is that glReadPixels() cannot be used after your content has been rendered to the screen in iOS 6.0+. You need to either have retained backing turned on for your CAEAGLLayer, or use glReadPixels() before `-presentRenderbuffer:` is called.

Comment: yes, I forget that point but now my issue is solved. when device capture image go some slow means stop few miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take screen shot then also try with that code & check:

```
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenRect.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: this code is generate a white image only not any graphics in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this this will take screenshot of view and save into device photo album.

```
-(IBAction)captureScreen:(id)sender
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *snapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```