# Capture ScreenShot with openGL

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want capture screen when any game is running with opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372292/i-want-capture-screen-when-any-game-is-running-with-opengl)

I am developing a action game with OpenGL.
When a best shot play by user I want to capture them and upload to social network.
I used many code but no success with then. Some code are on:

[OpenGL ES View Snapshot](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html)

```
       NSInteger myDataLength = 480 * 320 * 4;

        // allocate array and read pixels into it.
        GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
        glReadPixels(0, 0, 480, 320, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

        // gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
        // there's gotta be a better way, but this works.
        GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
        for(int y = 0; y < 320; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < 480 * 4; x++)
            {
                buffer2[(319 - y) * 480 * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * 480 + x];
            }
        }


        // make data provider with data.
        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);

        // prep the ingredients
        int bitsPerComponent = 8;
        int bitsPerPixel = 32;
        int bytesPerRow = 4 * 480;
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
        CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

        // make the cgimage
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(480, 320, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO,   renderingIntent);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

*And Other Code Is :*

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenRect.size, NO, 0.0);
[glview.parent.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But All Code Generate Image In Simulator Not In Device(Black or white image only)

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered here. Here is what I believe you are looking for

[How to get UIImage from EAGLView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352864/how-to-get-uiimage-from-eaglview/1945733)

Comment: This explains the black image - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857912/saving-imageref-from-glpaint-creates-completely-black-image